# How do I keep track of requests issued/completed without the use of additional state variables? (Java/Grpc)

Tags: java, stream, request, grpc

I am using the [StreamObserver](http://www.grpc.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/stub/StreamObserver.html) class found in the grpc-java project to set up some bidirectional streaming.

When I run my program, I make an undetermined number of requests to the server, and I only want to call onCompleted() on the requestObserver once I have finished making all of the requests.

Currently, to solve this, I am using a variable "inFlight" to keep track of the requests that have been issued, and when a response comes back, I decrement "inFlight". So, something like this.

```
// issuing requests
while (haveRequests) {
    MessageRequest request = mkRequest();
    this.requestObserver.onNext(request);
    this.inFlight++; 
}


// response observer
StreamObserver<Message> responseObserver = new StreamObserver<Message> {

    @Override
    public void onNext(Message response) {
        if (--this.onFlight == 0) {
            this.requestObserver.onCompleted();
        }

        // work on message
    }

    // other methods

}
```

A bit pseudo-codey, but this logic works. However, I would like to get rid of the "inFlight" variable if possible. Is there anything within the StreamObserver class that allows this sort of functionality, without the need of an additional variable to track state? Something that would tell the number of requests issued and when they completed.

I've tried inspecting the object within the intellij IDE debugger, but nothing is popping out to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your direct question, you can simply call onComplete from the while loop.  All the messages passed to `onNext`.  Under the hood, gRPC will send what is called a "half close", indicating that it won't send any more messages, but it is willing to receive them.  Specifically:

```
// issuing requests
while (haveRequests) {
    MessageRequest request = mkRequest();
    this.requestObserver.onNext(request);
    this.inFlight++; 
}
requestObserver.onCompleted();
```

This ensures that all responses are sent, and in the order that you sent them.  On the server side, when it sees the corresponding `onCompleted` callback, it can half-close its side of the connection by calling onComplete on its observer.  (There are two observers on the server side one for receiving info from the client, one for sending info).

Back on the client side, you just need to wait for the server to half close to know that all messages were received and processed.  Note that if there were any errors, you would get an `onError` callback instead.

If you **don't** know how many requests you are going to make on the client side, you might consider using an `AtomicInteger`, and call `decrementAndGet` when you get back a response.  If the return value is `0`, you'll know all the requests have completed.

Comment: Yea, I don't know until runtime how many requests I will be issuing. You can think of this like the unix "tree" command. If something is a directory, I will do an "ls" to the server, if something is a file, I will just print it out. But I don't know ahead of time the directory structure. So, the number of "ls" commands I make to the server are unknown until runtime.

Comment: If that's the case, then you'll have to keep track of the number of outstanding RPCs yourself.  Not everyone needs the functionality, so we keep it out of the API to make it faster for those people.  Having an extra counter to keep track of the number of responses still expected doesn't seem all that bad.